# Initializing a tabPanel

Tags: shiny, lazy-loading

I'm looking for initializing all contents of a tab in shiny because another part of my app is reactive to that tab. I tried `outputOptions(output, "object_name", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)` but it works only on some of the uiOutputs:

All I need is my uiOutputs are initialized. I'm using bsCollapse which needs to be expanded in order to initialize uiOutputs inside it:

```
tabPanel(
  "Plots",
  
  # Adding the additional elements here before the sub-tabsetPanel
  bsCollapse(
    id = "collapseExample",
    open = "AR_plot_filters",
    bsCollapsePanel(
      "Click for all the filters.",
      HTML(
        '<div style="color:red; text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
                                  Use the following filters to plot parameters.</div>'
      ),
      
      fluidRow(
        class = "my-fluid-row2 vcenter",
        column(
          5,
          align = 'center',
          div(uiOutput("station_type_AR"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;"),
          div(uiOutput("station_AR"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;"),
          div(uiOutput("par_type_AR"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;"),
          div(uiOutput("season_par"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;", class = "radio-group"),
          div(uiOutput("exceedance_par"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;")
        ),
        column(
          7,
          div(uiOutput("exceedance_AR"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;"),
          div(uiOutput("exceedance_AR_peak"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;"),
          div(uiOutput("exceedance_AR_limit"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;"),
          div(uiOutput("exceedance_AR_guideline"), style = "margin-bottom: -10px;")
        )
      ),
      style = "success"
    )
  )
```

I tried to initialize each of the uiOutputs one by one (Note: the uiOutputs are reactive to items above them, for example "season_par" is chosen based on "station_AR", etc.)

```
  outputOptions(output, "station_type_AR", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "station_AR", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "season_par", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "exceedance_par", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "exceedance_AR", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "exceedance_AR_peak", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "exceedance_AR_limit", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  outputOptions(output, "exceedance_AR_guideline", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

But for some of them I got the error, for example:

```
Warning: Error in .subset2(x, "impl")$outputOptions: exceedance_par is not in list of output objects
  41: stop
  40: .subset2(x, "impl")$outputOptions
  39: outputOptions
  38: server [(directory)R#2137]
   1: runApp
Error in .subset2(x, "impl")$outputOptions(name, ...) : 
  exceedance_par is not in list of output objects
```

It's understandable that it might be difficult to initialize all of the uiOutputs together at the beginning because some of them are reactive to items above them. So any solution to make the whole tab non-lazy is much appreciated.